# How to retrieve a specific value within a map function?

Tags: erlang

I have this function :

```
Headers = "hellohellohello".
lists:map(fun(X) -> isExists(X,Headers) end, ["h","he","hell","hello",...]).
```

The result is a list of Boolean, lets say :

```
[false,false,false,true,...]
```

Note that the result contain one "true"
I would like to get the value of the :

> true

which is

> "hello"

in our case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`lists:filter/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#filter-2) to get a list of results for which `isExists/2` returns true:

```
1> Headers = "hellohellohello".
"hellohellohello"
2> lists:filter(fun(X) -> isExists(X,Headers) end, ["h","he","hell","hello"]).
["hello"]
```

But that returns a list, not a value. Alternatively, you could use [`lists:map/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#map-2) to pair each value in the list with the result of passing it to `isExists/2`, and then use [`lists:keyfind/3`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#keyfind-3) to extract the result:

```
4> lists:keyfind(true, 1, lists:map(fun(X) -> {isExists(X,Headers), X} end, ["h","he","hell","hello"])).
{true,"hello"}
```

But this alternative requires multiple list traversals, and it returns a tuple from which you'd have to extract the value.

Perhaps the best alternative is to use [`lists:foldl/3`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#foldl-3):

```
3> lists:foldl(fun(X,Acc) -> case isExists(X,Headers) of true -> X; false -> Acc end end, false, ["h","he","hell","hello"]).
"hello"
```

If there are no matching results, the initial value of the accumulator, which in this example is `false`, will be returned instead.